# Schrödinger's Equation and the depth of a finite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

Before I ask my question, I have to stress: I have absolutely **no** idea what the math is going on. I've read my textbook, several Wikipedia articles, scoured the internet, and don't feel anymore knowledgeable after hours of reading. I am frustrated beyond belief—I apologize if the quality of this post decreases because of that. Here's the question I'm working on (but any illumination of the surrounding concepts is much appreciated; the question itself doesn't have to be answered at all, I'd just like to have some idea of what I'm doing):

> A finite square well 1.0 fm wide contains one neutron. How deep must the well be if there are
>   only two allowed energy levels for the neutron?

I know that Schrödinger's Wave Equation is:

[image: this]

Which is all fine and dandy... but what is it? I understand what it is *mathematically*, but that isn't telling me anything of why it's useful. Did Schrödinger just plug De  Broglie's relationships into the wave equation, call it a day, and get famous? What is this a wave of?  What's it supposed to *be*? This equation is so out of all context for me that just working with it is made more difficult. My textbook says:

> The reasoning followed by Schrödinger is somewhat difficult and not important for our purposes.

But then goes on to throw around some constants and make some assumptions about $\Psi(r,t)$ in order for it to... preform some undisclosed magical wave-matter-related things.

From what I've read, all I can gather is that—in solving this problem—I have to construct wave-equations for various potentials inside and outside of some "well"? What is the well? There's something about even and odd parity, which I think refers to there needing to be a whole-number of wavelengths within that 1 fm range (why?), but otherwise I'm pretty much dead in the water.

This isn't a Quantum Mechanics class in particular; it's a general "Modern Physics" class. So far, the whole of the class seems to be randomly tossing out equations, constants, and relationships without context, derivation, or motivation—this confusion has become a very unfortunate (and frustrating) standard for the class. (And I *despise* the textbook. Help me. :l)

Comment: A quote as a starter: Where did we get that [Schrödinger's equation] from? It's not possible to derive it from anything you know. It came out of the mind of Schrödinger.
The Feynman Lectures on Physics

Comment: You have a lot of questions.  It would be more effective for you to talk it over with your instructor.  Short version: you have to give up the notion that "something" is waving.  Schrodinger's Equation cannot be derived.  It can be *motivated*, but I don't think that will help your understanding.  Talk to your instructor.  Update: @Lord_Gestalter may be on to something.  Feynmann's Lectures may help with these questions more than your textbook.

Comment: You may also want to check the Wiki page at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well. In particular, the section "Finding wavefunctions for the bound state" gives an explicit method to determine the number of bound states, which only needs the single parameter $u_0=mL^2V_0/(2\hbar^2),$ which your problem gives to you indirectly.

Answer (score 2):

First: The Schrödinger equation is a equation using functionals. Solutions to this equation are such $\Psi(r,t)$, that fulfill this equation. 
The finite square well 1.0 fm wide means you have a potential $V(r)$ which is zero for r<0 and r>1fm and -d in between. d is your depth.
Now you have to determine d such, that only two of the resulting $\Psi(r,t)$ fulfilling the Schrödinger Equation are bound.

This isn't a complete solution, but should help you for your studies in textbooxs, where the square well is a standard example.

Answer (score 2):

In Mathematica, using the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well#Finding_wavefunctions_for_the_bound_state) $\sqrt{u_0^2-v^2}=\begin{cases}\\v\tan(v) \\-v\cot(v)\end{cases}$ where $u_0=mL^2V_0/(2\hbar^2)$, we can first compute $u_0$:

```
<< PhysicalConstants`
u = Convert[
  NeutronMass (1 Femto Meter)^2 V0 ElectronVolt/(2 \
PlanckConstantReduced^2), 1]

Out: 1.20649*10^-8 V0
```

Since $u_0$ is typically on the order of an integer, you know $V0$ has to be on the order of $10^8$. Plotting reveals that

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Sqrt[u^2 - v^2] - v Tan[v], 
Sqrt[u^2 - v^2] + v Cot[v]} /. V0 -> 2 10^8], {v, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

has two zeros (excluding the discontinuity line, which is a graphing artifact of the $\tan$ function), so $V_0\approx2\times10^8\text{eV}$ is about right. Atomic nuclei have diameters on the order of several femtometers, so this gives you a very approximate lower bound on the order of magnitude of the binding potential needed to hold a nucleus together.

If you are unsatisfied with the exposition your class is providing, Section 5.2 of the 2nd Edition of Eisberg and Resnick's *Quantum Physics* has an extremely good plausibility "derivation" of Schrodinger's equation.

Comment: If you add `, Exclusions -> Cos[v] == 0, PlotPoints -> 150` to `Plot` options, you'll get rid of the vertical asymptote line, still preserving visual continuity of purple line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only way I got into schrødinger:

1: Derive maxwell equations

2: Solve them for a chargeless particle

3:

Manipulate the answer from 2 like in this text. Read the part about wave packets first by hitting the tab up in the link below and try to put a wave packet ito maxwell would work I believe.

http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node28.html

All is just linear additions actually

Comment: What is step 3?

Comment: Sorry. Step three is doing what I wrote after it. In the link they end up with schrødinger time dependent with V=0 and extends it to with V afterwards.